# VBscript error: Object required: 'wscript'

Tags: vbscript, delphi-xe

Could someone tell me why does this line error:

```
set my_obj = wscript.CreateObject("ObjectTest","pref_")
```

It gives this error:

> Object required: 'wscript'

If I run this code:

```
Set WScript = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
set my_obj = CreateObject("ObjectTest","pref_")
```

I get this error instead:

> Object doesn't support this property or method: 'CreateObject'

I'm running the vbscript from within a Delphi app.

Comment: A similar error can be generated if you run the same script in this app:  http://www.scalabium.com/smscript.htm

Answer (score 2):

> Object required: 'wscript'
>
> I'm running the vbscript from within a Delphi app.

This is why your script is failing.  The `wscript` object is only defined when the script is run by `wscript.exe`.  To do what you are attempting, you need to implement your own object and provide it to the script environment for the script code to access when needed.

Assuming you are using [`IActiveScript`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ky29ffxd.aspx) to run your script, you can write a COM Automation object that implements the [`IDispatch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221608.aspx) interface, and then you can create an instance of that object and give it to the [`IActiveScript.AddNamedItem()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s8eyc3sh.aspx) method before then calling [`IActiveScript.SetScriptState()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xd9bt7sb.aspx) to start running the script.

For example, write an Automation object that exposes its own `CreateObject()` method, give it to `AddNamedItem()` with a name of `App`, and then the script can call `App.CreateObject()`.  Your `CreateObject()` implementation can then create the real requested object and hook up event handlers to it as needed.  To fire events back into the script, use the [`IActiveScript.GetScriptDispatch()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5b043ew.aspx) method to retrieve an `IDispatch` for the desired procedure defined in the script, and then use [`IDispatch.Invoke()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221479.aspx) with DISPID 0 and the `DISPATCH_METHOD`
 flag to execute that procedure with the desired input parameters.

Your object can implement any properties and methods that you want the script to have access to.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your script is failing is due to a few occurrences.

1. DO **NOT** use "`WScript`" as an object especially while coding in `Windows-Based Script Host`(or `WSH`), as the program assumes you are running `wscript.exe` or calling `WScript` commands.
2. Use `Dim`! If the first rule wasn't null, this is why. Using command "`Option Explicit`" in VBScript requires users to `Dim` any `object` or calling of an `object`.

A fixed code would be:

```
Option Explicit
Dim 1, 2
Set 1 = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set 2 = WScript.CreateObject("ObjectTest", "pref_")
```